# Error: There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou tentando relacionar essas duas tabelas

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'Periodo') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE Periodo
GO
CREATE TABLE Periodo(
    Numero tinyint NOT NULL,
    SiglaCurso varchar(5) NOT NULL,
    AnoGrade int NOT NULL,
    SemestreGrade char(1) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Periodo] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
    Numero ASC,
    SiglaCurso ASC,
    AnoGrade ASC,
    SemestreGrade ASC
))
GO
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'GradeCurricular') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE GradeCurricular
GO
CREATE TABLE GradeCurricular(
    SiglaCurso varchar(5) NOT NULL,
    Ano int NOT NULL,
    Semestre char(1) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_GradeCurricular] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
    SiglaCurso ASC,
    Ano ASC,
    Semestre ASC
))
GO

ALTER TABLE Periodo
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_PeriodoGrade_Ano
FOREIGN KEY (AnoGrade) REFERENCES GradeCurricular(Ano)
GO

ALTER TABLE Periodo
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_PeriodoGrade_Semestre
FOREIGN KEY (SemestreGrade) REFERENCES GradeCurricular(Semestre)
GO
```

Ao tentar criar essas duas chaves estrangeiras recebo a seguinte mensagem:

> Msg 1776, Level 16, State 0, Line 2 There are no primary or candidate
>   keys in the referenced table 'GradeCurricular' that match the
>   referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK_PeriodoGrade_Ano'. Msg
>   1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 2 Could not create constraint. See
>   previous errors.

Onde está o erro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A chave primária da sua tabela `GradeCurricular` é composta. Você só pode fazer relacionamentos fortes se as duas chaves - primária e estrangeira - tiverem o mesmo formato. Logo, suas chaves estrangeiras devem ser compostas também, para apontar para as três colunas da chave primária (`SiglaCurso`, `Ano` e `Semestre`).

Eu entendo que você deve ter feito essa chave primária composta assim para permitir que dois cursos estejam no mesmo ano e no mesmo semestre, e ainda assim garantir alguma forma de identidade para cada curso. Você vai sofrer muito menos se utilizar um design mais simples, utilizado um número autoincrementado como chave primária. Depois você pode adicionar uma restrição do tipo `unique` nas três colunas que hoje você utiliza para identificar um curso.

Comment: Primeiramente, obrigado!.
Gostaria de mostrar o modelo porém nao vou conseguir, talvez eu tenha me confundido, mas beleza... Entendi!

Comment: Posso então tornar essas colunas identidade(IDENTITY)?

Comment: @AlissonFerrari Uma coluna do tipo *identity* nunca pode ter o valor repetido. Seus cursos devem ter valores repetidos de ano e semestre, mesmo que a combinação ano, sigla e semestre não se repita, certo? Se for para usar *identity*, que seja em uma coluna de ID que exista apenas para dar um identificador realmente único para uma linha.